# jQuery function ignore class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, class

I've got an interesting situation. I'm building a music page using an open source flash music player that degrades to html for mobile users. I've got everything working great except for one issue.. and that is that one of my Javascript functions is interfering, specifically an anchor color fade.

There are many hidden buttons involved in the player, but the play/pause button has a translucent anchor underneath it and code is forcing this to be shown when the buttons are hovered over.

I can't seem to get the syntax correct using the not function.. But I'll settle for anything that works!

Thank you!

HTML

```
<div class="sc-player">
```

Javascript

```
jQuery(function ($) {
     $('a').not('div.sc-player').each(function () {
         var $el = $(this),
             orig = $el.css('color');
         $el.hover(function () {
             $el.stop().animate({ color: '#00B0D9' }, 400);
         },function () {
             $el.stop().animate({ color: orig }, 400);
         });
     });
 });
```

Comment: What framework are you using? Prototype? Mootools? (It's clearly not jQuery, which is what I know.)

Comment: Hey Phrogz, edited the question in response. It's within MooTool. Do you know if a jQuery function can be written to replace it? and ideally solving my above problem as well. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery (make sure you've got the color animation plugin from jQ UI: http://jqueryui.com/demos/animate/):

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('a.a').each(function () {
        var $el = $(this),
            orig = $el.css('color');
        if ($el.parents('.sc-player').length!=0) return;
        $el.hover(function () {
            $el.stop().animate({ color: '#00B0D9' }, 400);
        },function () {
            $el.stop().animate({ color: orig }, 400);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: the morph works great with the jQuery UI add on.. unfortunately i'm still having trouble with the links within div.sc-player fading into view.. and now they're white by default instead of translucent

Comment: Couldn't tell you why.  I made an adjustment above to try and alleviate the problem.